# How to dynamically set color code groups in gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, colors, alternate

I have a gridview that looks like below...

[image]

Dynamically I need to alternate the gridview colors per patient.
Patient 1 should have grey color (2 records)
Patient 2 should alternate and have blue color (2 records)
Patient 3 should alternate and have grey color (2 records)
Patient 4 should alternate and have blue color (2 records)

Not all patients have 2 records. Some will have only one while others can have more than 2, but I need the colors to alternate between different patients.

I cannot figure out how to do this...Please can someone help?

I'm using VS 2019, C#, asp.net (this is prior to MVC).

Thanks,
Ninel

I tried this:

```
protected void grdPatientList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        NewMRN = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;

        if (counter == 1)
        {
            LastMRN = NewMRN;
        }

        if (LastMRN != NewMRN)
        {
            ColorToggle = true;
            mrnvalue = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
        }
        else
        {
            ColorToggle = false;
        }

        if (ColorToggle == true)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
        }
        LastMRN = NewMRN;
        counter++;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `LastMRN` variable is not shared between each event handler function call. One way is to add an OnDataBound event handler which fires after all databinding of the grid are done.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">


protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isGray = false;
    string prevNumber = “”;
    for(int i = 0; i<GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        if (row.Cells[2].Text != prevNumber)
        {
            isGray = !isGray;
        }
        row.BackColor = isGray ? System.Drawing.Color.Gray : System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
        prevNumber = row.Cells[2].Text;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, You can still use the RowDataBound event and read the patient number and color of the previous row instead. (Or you can store `lastMRN` and `lastColor` outside the function, though a bit more messy.)

```
protected void grdPatientList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Drawing.Color prevColor = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1].BackColor;
            string prevNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1].Cells[2].Text;
            if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == prevNumber)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = prevColor;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = prevColor == System.Drawing.Color.Gray ? System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue : System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```